# iPad shows blue screen video after reverse and launch on device

Tags: xcode

I am developing an app for reverse video play.
When I installed it on the iPad the video plays but with a blue overlay.

Is there any version issue or anything else ? please anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: how to solve this problem? For reverse video i am using RCToolbox  in iOS

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB` to `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` in `RCImageSequencer` class